# Get selected columns of foreign key table using Criteria Query API

Tags: java, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I have 3 tables ONE, TWO and THREE.

In table ONE I have 2 foreign keys, 'ONE_foreignKey1' and 'ONE_foreignKey2'. 
'ONE_foreignKey2' is foreign key of table TWO and table TWO have foreign key of table THREE.

I want some selected columns from table THREE using table ONE foreign key 'ONE_foreignKey1' that I passed in my Java rest api.

```
Table ONE
id | ONE_foreignKey1 | ONE_foreignKey2(table TWO)

Table TWO
id | foreignKey of Table THREE

Table THREE
id | name | status
```

so i want to fetch id ,name and status of table THREE from using table ONE's foreign key 'ONE_foreignKey1' that i passed in my API parameter.

Comment: maybe the ER diagram would help to understand...or at least the essential SQL  scripts.